# C# MySQL encountering fatal error when inserting data into my table

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

I have a method called 'AddUser' which is suppose to insert data into my table but whenever I execute it a MySqlException is thrown.

*Exception message:*

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

**My columns:**

```
Column          Type         Null   Default           Comments
Identity Number int(11)      No                       auto_increment
Full Name       varchar(32)  No          
Birthday        date         No          
Sex             varchar(6)   No          
City            varchar(32)  No          
Region          varchar(32)  No          
Zip Code        varchar(10)  No          
Country         varchar(32)  No          
Phone Number    varchar(15)  No          
Email Address   varchar(255) No          
Ticket Number   varchar(8)   No          
Registration    timestamp    No     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**My code:**

```
private MySqlConnection mySqlConnection;

private async void OpenConnection()
{
    if (mySqlConnection == null)
    {
        mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
    }
    await mySqlConnection.OpenAsync();
}

private async void CloseConnection()
{
    if (mySqlConnection != null)
    {
        await mySqlConnection.CloseAsync();
    }
}

private async Task<bool> AddUser(
    string fullName,
    string birthday,
    string sex,
    string city,
    string region,
    string zipCode,
    string country,
    string phoneNumber,
    string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        OpenConnection();
        MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Users (Identity_Number, Full_Name, Birthday, Sex, City, Region, Zip_Code, Country, Phone_Number, Email_Address, Ticket_Number, Registration_Time) VALUES (@Identity_Number, @Full_Name, @Birthday, @Sex, @City, @Region, @Zip_Code, @Country, @Phone_Number, @Email_Address, @Ticket_Number, @Registration_Time);");
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Full_Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fullName;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Birthday", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = birthday;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Sex", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sex;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@City", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = city;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Region", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = region;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Zip_Code", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = zipCode;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Country", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = country;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone_Number", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = phoneNumber;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email_Address", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailAddress;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Ticket_Number", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().GetHashCode().ToString("X");

        await mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();



CloseConnection();
            mySqlCommand.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Would someone be able to inspect my code and let me know what I'm doing wrong? And also maybe how I can improve my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont need `Identity_Number` in the query - MySQL will generate it, you also dont supply a value for it so there are more params than values

Comment: `Registration` is called `Registration_Time` in the query, and both `identity_number` and `Registration_time` are used as parameters in the query, but parameters with those names are never added. I think you may want to just leave them up altogether and use the default values.

Comment: When doing Inserts into a Table that has an auto increment attribute set on the column, you exclude the inserting of that column. if you need to know what the value of the identity field is, then use the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() into @SomeReturnValue`

Comment: @Steve yes I am aware of it but the OP can do the equivalent that's my point..

Comment: Look at the InnerException, it will contain the real MySQL exception

Comment: @Plutonix I removed `Identity_Number` from the query but I'm still getting the same error. Since `Registration_Time` works similarly to `Identity_Number` I removed that as well to see if it would work but then it says _Unknown column 'Full_Name' in 'field list'._.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson I made a small mistake in my post. The column's name is `Registration_Time` in the database.

Comment: well your SQL query calls it `Full_Name` but the table looks like it uses `Full Name`

Comment: @Plutonix I thought you had to use an underscore instead of a white space in the query. Is this not correct? For example if the column name is _Fax Number_ in the database, it would be _Fax_Number_ in the query

Comment: @Plutonix I removed the the underscore and used a white space but now I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: That is not correct.  MySQL uses back ticks for escaping poorly named columns, but I think this might be configurable.  So `Full Name` would be ` + Full Name + ` .  Also, `User` is a reserved word, and I would not tempt the Fates with `Users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Plutonix for your answer. I removed the underscore and escaped the column names containing spaces in them with back ticks as you suggested. The code works now.

```
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO Users (`Full Name`, Birthday, Sex, City, Region, `Zip Code`, Country, `Phone Number`, `Email Address`, `Ticket Number`) VALUES (@Full_Name, @Birthday, @Sex, @City, @Region, @Zip_Code, @Country, @Phone_Number, @Email_Address, @Ticket_Number);");
```